# Continuity of the derivative of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is it true, that if $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable on an interval $[a;b]$, then  $f'(x)$ is continuous? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if $x=|x-c|$   Check differentiability at $x=c$

Comment: Do you mean: if f is continuous and differentiable on [a,b]?

Comment: A continuous function doesn't necessarily **have** a derivative at all - thus, as Jonas says, did you intend to require that $f$ be differentiable?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to edit that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
$$
f(x) =\begin{cases} x^2\sin\frac 1x &\text{ if } x\neq 0\\
0 &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

- It is smooth everywhere, because
  $$
  |f(x)|\le x^2 \implies \text{ continuous in }0\\
  \left|\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}\right|\le |x| \implies \text{ has a derivative in }0\ \ \  (f'(0) = 0)
  $$

  - Now its derivative is, around $0$ (and for $x\neq 0$):
    $$
    f'(x) = 2x\sin\frac 1x - \sin\frac 1x = O(x) - \sin\frac 1x
    $$

and is not continuous: it takes all values of $[-1,1]$ in any neighborhood of $0$.